# Does Mac have something similar to a Linux loop device (alternative to losetup)?

Tags: hard-drive, unix

I am trying to work with some CD and hard drive images that I will run inside of QEMU. On Linux, I mount the images using the `losetup` command, but I notice Mac does not have this.

Is there something similar I could use instead?

Answer (score 19):

You can use `hdiutil` for that. Basically, it does the same as `losetup` on Linux.

If you are planning to work with images with non-standard layouts or filesystems (for example, live CDs), make sure to pass `-nomount` to `hdiutil attach`, as otherwise it will complain that it couldn’t mount it (it tries to mount everything by default).

After the image is attached, it will appear in `diskutil list` as an ordinary disk. You can work with it just like with a physical disc.

---

Here is an example of mounting a live CD:

```
$ hdiutil attach -nomount path/to/file.iso
/dev/disk2              FDisk_partition_scheme
/dev/disk2s2            0xEF
```

It prints the name of the new disk. Now we can see it:

```
$ diskutil list

<...>

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +453.0 MB   disk2
   1:                       0xEF                         12.6 MB    disk2s2
```

This is a live CD, it uses [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) file system. You can’t mount it using `diskutil`, you have to use a special tool:

```
$ mount_cd9660 /dev/disk2 ~/tmp/mnt
```

When you are done, unmount and detach:

```
$ umount /dev/disk2
$ hdiutil detach disk2
"disk2" unmounted.
"disk2" ejected.
```

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X has the Disk Images Framework for live mounting disk images. Although it primarily works with its own native formats such as .dmg, I believe it can also work with .iso's and other formats. You can use Disk Utility or the hdiutil command to mount disk images.

Comment: I was trying to use the hdiutil command with attack -mount optional, since the images do not have a file system. However, I'm not sure what to do after that, since it does not appear anywhere.